# Сортировка ключевых слов из фрейма данных

Tags: python, база-данных, pandas

Необходимо написать геоклассификатор, который сможет задавать географическую принадлежность определенного региона к каждой строке. Т.е., если поисковый запрос содержит название города региона, то название этого региона записывается в столбец ‘регион’. Если поисковый запрос не содержит названия города, то поставьте "не определено".
У меня есть следующий код, который не работает.

```
import pandas as pd
data_location = pd.read_csv(r'\Users\super\Desktop\keywords.csv', sep = ',')
def sorting(row):
    keyword_set = row['keywords'].lower()
    for region, city_list in geo_data.items():
        for town in keyword_set:
            if town in city_list:
                return region
 
        return 'undefined'
```

Правила распределения по регионам Центр, Северо-Запад и Дальний Восток:

```
geo_location = {
'Центр': ['москва', 'тула', 'ярославль'],

'Северо-Запад': ['петербург', 'псков', 'мурманск'],

'Дальний Восток': ['владивосток', 'сахалин', 'хабаровск']
}
```

Ссылка на файл csv, который используется в программе https://dropmefiles.com/IurAn

Я попытался отсортировать функцию, но она не работает, была идея создать шаблон для всех существующих городов и запускать каждую строку файла через этот шаблон для сортировки.

**Заранее прошу прощения за такой обширный вопрос, я все еще новичок в этой области и только учусь. Я буду рад получить различные советы и помощь.**

Comment: список городов для поиска у вас наверняка же будет расширяться и меняться? а как вы хотите выделять в строке названия городов, состоящие из нескольких слов (Старый Оскол, например), или морфологически измененные (в ялте, например)? у вас сейчас 100000 строк в файле, как-то тяжело это все ворочаться будет.

Comment: @strawdog, ну возможно можно сделать так, чтобы сортировались хотя бы те города, которые содержаться в geo_location. 
Ведь если вносить все города, которые есть то необходим еще 1 файл или датафрейм, в котором перечислены все города России.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, я бы попробовал так:

```
df["регион"] = pd.NA
for k in geo_location.keys():
    df.loc[df["keyword"].str.contains('|'.join(geo_location[k])), "регион"]=k
# в df теперь строки, где ключевые слова нашлись, имеют регион, 
# а те, где ключевых слов не нашлось - имеют pd.NA

res = df[df["регион"].notnull()] # для примера отберем только те строки,
                                 # которые имеют регион
print(res)
```

```
                                     keyword   shows          регион
127                             авито москва  979292           Центр
370                 авито ру санкт петербург  425134    Северо-Запад
564                погода в санкт петербурге  292489    Северо-Запад
849                          авито ярославль  209581           Центр
1063                     фарпост владивосток  176951  Дальний Восток
...                                      ...     ...             ...
99590  авито ярославль автомобили с пробегом    3673           Центр
99634   северпост новости мурманской области    3606    Северо-Запад
99808      полармед мурманск запись на прием    3719    Северо-Запад
99890                    яндекс метро москва    4548           Центр
99922                      авто ру ярославль    3712           Центр
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за решение, оно работает круто. Также благодарен за метод pd.NA, не знал о нём. Благодарен.

Answer (score 0):

У вас там сразу несколько ошибок, плюс я кое-что оптимизировал:

```
import pandas as pd

# Тут путь не смотрите, мне так удобнее было грузить в Colab
data_location = pd.read_csv('keywords.csv', sep = ',')

# Я сразу преобразовал списки в множества, так чуть быстрее будет работать
geo_data = {
'Центр': {'москва', 'тула', 'ярославль'},
'Северо-Запад': {'петербург', 'псков', 'мурманск'},
'Дальний Восток': {'владивосток', 'сахалин', 'хабаровск'}
}

def sorting(row):
    # Тут нужно разбить на отдельные слова через split, вы этого не сделали
    # Ну и сразу делаю множество чтобы быстрее
    keyword_set = set(row['keyword'].lower().split())
    for region, city_list in geo_data.items():
        # Так быстрее проверять, чем перебором
        if keyword_set & city_list:
            return region
    # Этот return у вас стоял внутри цикла, что неправильно
    # В результате определялся только Центр
    return 'undefined'

data_location['location'] = data_location.apply(sorting, axis=1)
```

Ну и ещё у вас было где-то `keywords` вместо `keyword` и `geo_location` вместо `geo_data`, надо всё-таки код проверять перед помещением в вопрос.

Естественно, таким методом не атрибутируются такие строки как:

```
авито санкт петербурге недвижимость
росреестр по санкт петербургу официальный сайт
```

При желании это тоже можно "найти" через какой-нибудь `fuzzy search`, но будет сложнее, сильно медленнее и не так надёжно.

Answer (score 0):

Итак, всем спасибо за решения. Они оба правильные.
Первый код работал идеально сразу же.
Второй код пришлось немного редактировать и вносить свои поправки.
Прикрепляю 2-й готовый код, ибо первый у вас уже есть.

```
import pandas as pd
data_location = pd.read_csv(r'\Users\super\Desktop\keywords.csv', sep = ',')
geo_data = {
'Центр': ['москва', 'тула', 'ярославль'],
'Северо-Запад': ['петербург', 'псков', 'мурманск'],
'Дальний Восток': ['владивосток', 'сахалин', 'хабаровск']
}
def sorting(row):
    keyword_set = set(row['keyword'].lower().split())
    for region, city_list in geo_data.items():
        if keyword_set.intersection(city_list):
            return region
    return 'undefined'
data_location['location'] = data_location.apply(sorting, axis=1)
data_location[data_location['location'] !='undefined'].head()
```